# Append Key and Value to a Key Value pair Dictionary Python

Tags: python

My intended goal is to append a key value pair to a value in inside of a dictionary:

I have the following:

```
crucial = {'C': {'C': 0, 'B': 1}}
done = {}
for each in crucial:
    for i in each:
        done['D'] = 0
        print(done)
        print(crucial[i].append(done))
```

The output is:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Programming Full-Stack\Python\Exercise Files\02 Quick Start\conditionals.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(crucial[i].append(done))
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
{'D': 0}
```

Expected output:

```
{'C': {'C': 0, 'B': 1, 'D':0}}
```

Therefore, can anyone provide me a guideline to append a key value pair to that value field in the outer dictionary?

Different approaches tried:  So far I've tried converting the dictionary to a list declaring d as [], not with {}. I also tried putting .extend instead of .append. But in none of those cases I've got the result I wanted.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Append and extend are methods for lists, not dictionaries.

Comment: use .update({a:b}) on dictionaries instead of .append()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error states, `dict` has no attribute `append`. There is no `append` method in the dictionary object. To assign a value to a particular key in a dictionary, it is simply:

```
d[key] = new_value
```

where new_value can be, if you wish: `{'a':1}`

If you are looking to update your dictionary with new data, you can use the update method.

```
d.update(new_stuff)
```

In your code, simply change your append, similar to the example I provided. I corrected it here:

```
crucial = {'C': {'C': 0, 'B': 1}}
done = {}
for each in crucial:
    for i in each:
        done['D'] = 0
        print(done)
        crucial[i].update(done)

print(crucial)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer my question.  The provided answer erases the content of the crucial list.  How can I include 'D': 0 to crucial instead of replacing the values?

Comment: @NellMartin Thanks for catching that. I fixed it. Try it out. Let me know if it worked out for you.

Comment: Thank you idjaw! That's the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Python has a update function to add new items to dictionary

```
crucial .update({'D':'0'})
```

Comment: @NellMartin -Thats easy and a single statement to easily add any items to a dictionary. If you are satisfied with my answer please mark it as answered

Comment: Thank you so much. It definitively helped me.  I learned something today!